# MSQL, retrieve all items even though it has not any matching foreign row

Tags: mysql, sql

title table

```
   | titleId | title |
       1       test5 
       2       test3
```

subscription table

```
   | userId | titleId |
       1       1
```

In this case user 1 subscribed to title test5.

what I would like to get:
return al titles, and if they have matching row for specified user, show that. For example for user 1 :

```
title | subscribed
test5      1
test3      -
```

I have come up with this:

```
SELECT title.id, title.title, subscribe.userId  FROM title   JOIN subscribe  ON title.id  = subscribe.uesrId 
where  subscribe.userId = 1;
```

---

```
title | subscribed
test5      1
```

I also would like to get below row

```
test3      -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, s.userId
FROM title t LEFT JOIN
     subscribe s
     ON t.id  = s.titleId AND s.userId = 1;
```

Note that the `WHERE` condition now has to go into the `ON` clause.

Also, the use of tables aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

And the `JOIN` condition should probably be on `titleid` not `userid`.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c592d/2) is a SQL Fiddle for the above query.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case "test5      1" returns twice.

Comment: I fixed that problem by adding "group by title.id" and it fixed it. Thanks, please update your answer with "group by".